# Working with recurring dates such as anniversaries, birthdays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to work with *recurring dates* in Javascript. For example, given a string representing the 24th of November (`--11-24`), I would like to get the next *occurence* of this *recurring date* in the future from a specified moment in time.

```
referencePoint = someLibraryForRecurringDates.referencePoint("1985-01-02");
nextOccurence = referencePoint.getNextOccurenceOf("--11-24");
// nextOccurence is a Date representing "1985-11-24"
```

Is there a Javascript library which treats the not-so-trivial domain of *recurring dates*?

Comment: https://github.com/jkbr/rrule - NB, this is better asked in [chat]

Comment: Annual recurrence sounds quite trivial to me. Or are you asking about a more general options?

Comment: @Bergi For example, what shall be done with a birthday on 29th of February. Or answering a question such as "given the day 2013-06-20, which is the closest anniversary occurence for "--01-17". There are significant subtleties with anniversary calculations that I would guess it's better to use a proven library instead of writing my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) will make such calculations easy:

```
// helpers:
Date.fromString = function(s) {
    s = s.match(/^(\d{4})-(\d\d?)-(\d\d?)$/);
    return new Date(s ? Date.UTC(+s[1], s[2]-1, +s[3]) : NaN);
};
Date.prototype.toDate = function() {
    return this.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+("0"+(this.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+this.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);
};

function getNextOccurence(referenceDate, desc) {
    desc = desc.match(/^--(\d\d?|-)-(\d\d?)$/);
    var next = new Date(referenceDate);
    if (!desc) return next;
    next.setUTCDate(+desc[2]);
    if (next < referenceDate) // if date is smaller than before
        next.setUTCMonth(next.getUTCMonth()+1); // advance month
    if (desc[1] != "-") {
        next.setUTCMonth(desc[1]-1);
        if (next < referenceDate) // if month is smaller than before
            next.setUTCFullYear(next.getUTCFullYear()+1); // advance year
    }
    return next;
}

// Tests:
> getNextOccurence(Date.fromString("1985-01-02"), "--11-24").toDate()
"1985-11-24"
> getNextOccurence(Date.fromString("2012-01-01"), "--02-29").toDate()
"2012-02-29"
> getNextOccurence(Date.fromString("2013-01-01"), "--02-29").toDate()
"2013-03-01"
> getNextOccurence(Date.fromString("2013-06-20"), "--01-17").toDate()
"2014-01-17"
```

Leap years and such will automatically be respected.